# Using the home (house) button in Logitech K400 keyboard

Tags: trackpad, keyboard

I've just bought the [Logitech K400](http://www.logitech.com/en-sg/support/keyboards/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400) keyboard/trackpad combo. The volume buttons above the keyboard works just fine. But the home button (that has a small "house" icon) doesn't do anything on OS X Lion.

Is there a way I can use it to display Launchpad? I've tried using System Preferences to use it as a "hot key" but it didn't register any key press there.

Comment: adib did you ever figure out how to use the house key on the k400? Device not found on Logi control center mac.

Comment: @user59521 I used a 3rd party keyboard tool that can map any function key to almost arbitrary actions. I forgot what it was and the iMac that was attached to the keyboard died a few months ago, hence couldn't revisit the setup.

Answer (score 3):

With my S530 I had to install the [Logitech Control Center for OS X](http://www.logitech.com/en-sg/support/software-hidden/3129) in order to configure the custom keys. Once you install that, you'll see a control center entry in your System Preferences panel:

[image]

Before you can assign a shortcut to the Home key on the keyboard, you need to make a keyboard shortcut for Launchpad as there is none by default. Open System Preferences and go to Keyboard settings. Click the Keyboard Shortcuts tab and select Launchpad & Dock. Make sure 'Show Launchpad' is checked and then double click over the area that shows the shortcut to assign a new shortcut (I used Alt-Cmd-L in the screen shot). If you can't assign a shortcut try unchecking and re-checking the Show Launchpad setting:

[image]

Now enter the Logitech Control Center, select your device and click the Configure button:

[image]

Click the Keys icon at the top to configure custom keys on the keyboard. Find the Home key in the list. Set the 'Assigned action' for the Home key to 'Keystroke. And configure the keystroke issued to be the one you assigned to Launchpad above. In my case it would be Alt-Cmd-L.

[image]

Comment: Strangely the K400 doesn't appear in Logitech Control Center's window (although the K400 is working and connected using the Unifying dongle that comes with it). I've updated LCC to the latest version 3.6.0.  Screeenshot: https://skitch.com/adib/891qp/logitech-control-center

Comment: Did you click the button on the bottom that says 'Add More Devices'?

Comment: you mean "Open Unifying Software" ? Yes.  https://skitch.com/adib/894um/logitech-unifying-software-advanced-view

Comment: No. See screen shots. It's called Control Center in my Preferences.

Comment: The Control Center screenshot was provided in first comment and there isn't any "Add More Devices" there.

Answer (score 0):

The K400 is not recognized on mac by logitech software. I think you need to rely on 3rd party things to customize behaviour. One tip I found out was that you can turn off touch to click by holding the blue FN key, and click the left mouse button on the trackpad.

Hope you can find a solution.